# NameError:name 'create_model' is not defined ....i have tried importing model from keras but it hasnt solved it .how to solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I tried creating a model using tensorflow. When I tried executing it shows me  [image: this]

the other files are in this link------- github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_chatbot

```
def train():

    enc_train, dec_train=data_utils.prepare_custom_data(
        gConfig['working_directory'])
    train_set = read_data(enc_train,dec_train)

def seq2seq_f(encoder_inputs,decoder_inputs,do_decode):
    return tf.nn.seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq(
        encoder_inputs,decoder_inputs, cell,
        num_encoder_symbols=source_vocab_size,
        num_decoder_symbols=target_vocab_size,
        embedding_size=size,
        output_projection=output_projection,
        feed_previous=do_decode)

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    model = create_model(sess,False)

    while True:
        sess.run(model)

        checkpoint_path = os.path.join(gConfig['working_directory'],'seq2seq.ckpt')
        model.saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=model.global_step)
```

other than this the other python files ive used are in the github link specified in the comments section below

this is the code defining create_model in the execute.py file

```
def create_model(session, forward_only):

  """Create model and initialize or load parameters"""
  model = seq2seq_model.Seq2SeqModel( gConfig['enc_vocab_size'], gConfig['dec_vocab_size'], _buckets, gConfig['layer_size'], gConfig['num_layers'], gConfig['max_gradient_norm'], gConfig['batch_size'], gConfig['learning_rate'], gConfig['learning_rate_decay_factor'], forward_only=forward_only)

  if 'pretrained_model' in gConfig:
      model.saver.restore(session,gConfig['pretrained_model'])
      return model

  ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(gConfig['working_directory'])
  # the checkpoint filename has changed in recent versions of tensorflow
  checkpoint_suffix = ""
  if tf.__version__ > "0.12":
      checkpoint_suffix = ".index"
  if ckpt and tf.gfile.Exists(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path + checkpoint_suffix):
    print("Reading model parameters from %s" % ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    model.saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
  else:
    print("Created model with fresh parameters.")
    session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  return model
```

Comment: Is this your full code as I don't see anything being imported or `create_model` being defined anywhere?

Comment: You should provide more info and context on the code. 
Is create_model a function you defined elsewhere in the code?
Is it a method imported from another model?

Comment: nope this is not the full code

Comment: im not able to post the full code as im a new user

Comment: i have not used it else where  -- https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_chatbot but used the files from here

Comment: if i have atleast ten  reputations to post images or codes

Comment: Is `create_model` your own user function or part of another module?

Comment: You have already posted code above, why can't you post the rest? An image would definetely not be a good idea anyway.

Comment: yep did it  .. and create_model is defind in the other python file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems like you have copied code but you did not structure it. If `create_model()` is defined in another file then you have to import it. Have you done that? (i.e. `from file_with_methods import create_model`). You should consider editing your post and adding more of your code, if you want us to help.

**Alternative**: You could also clone the github repository(that you shared in your comment) and just change whatever you want to change in the `execution.py` file. This way you can keep the "hierarchy" that the owner uses and you could add your own code where needed.

Comment: i cloned the github and placed it in my folder but it still doesnt work

Comment: Well, that's not possible. There is probably something wrong with the way you have your files organized. Cloning this repository should work.

Comment: thanx yeah i hadnt cloned the repositoryy